# Ofstream not writing to file C++

Tags: c++, file, io, ofstream

I have this method which supposed to get a buffer and write some content to a file:

```
void writeTasksToDevice()
{

TaskInfo *task;
unsigned int i = lastTaskWritten;

printf("writing elihsa\n");
outputFile.write(" Elisha2", 7);
//pthread_mutex_lock(&fileMutex);

for(; i < (*writingTasks).size(); i++)
{
    task = (*writingTasks).at(i);
    if(NULL == task)
    {
        printf("ERROR!!! in writeTasksToDevice - there's a null task in taskQueue. By "
                " design that should NEVER happen\n");
        exit(-1);

    }
    if(true == task->wasItWritten)
    {
        //continue;
    }
    else // we've found a task to write!
    {

        printf("trying to write buffer to file\n");
        printf("buffer = %s, length = %d\n", task->buffer, task->length);<====PRINT HERE IS OK< PRINTING WHAT IS WANTED
        outputFile.write(task->buffer, task->length); <===SHOULD WRITE HERE
        printf("done writing file\n");
    }

}

//pthread_mutex_unlock(&fileMutex);


// TODO: check if we should go to sleep and wait for new tasks
// and then go to sleep




}
```

the buffer content is:

task->buffer: `elishaefla`

task->length: `10`

i opened the stream in another init function using:

```
outputFile.open(fileName, ios :: app);
if(NULL == outputFile)
{
    //print error;
    return -1;
}
```

but at the end, the file content is empty, nothing is being written.

any idea why?

Comment: At what point did you check? NOte that it is most likely buffering, so before checking you need to flush or close the stream

Comment: Change parameters to ios::out | ios::app

Comment: @luskan: If it's indeed ofstream then it doesn't matter: ios::out is guaranteed to be ORed into the flags.

Comment: @luskan still not writing anything...

Comment: Removed c tag as this is purtely c++ question

Comment: @PlasmaHH i dint think it matters in this case, im trying to write to file in the 6th line, and it does write  "Elisha2"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not provide enough information to answer the question with certainty, but here are some of the issues you might be facing:

1. You did not flush the buffer of the `ofstream`
2. You did not close the file that you are trying to open later on (if I'm correct, `outputFile` is a global variable, so it is not closed automatically until the end of the program)

Comment: please note that in the 6th line the string: "Elisha2" is being written, why does this happen?

Comment: My guess would be that since you do some more writing, the buffer fills up and previous contents are flushed automatically.

Comment: Attila, you are right. so when should i flush the buffer? when the program ends or after each write to file?

Comment: You can do a `flush()` after each write, or at any convenient sequence point (e.g. at the end of a few subsequent calls to `write()` if there is a performance issue from too frequent flushing

Comment: In my situation, I already had a file in `/tmp/text.txt` -  I opened it with `std::_S_trunc`, did a `flush()` and a `close()` which did nothing. But the file was open. I had to delete it and let my C++ program create it, then it updated fine.